# Is there a way to reduce the if else cases?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
let invert = moreIsBetter.includes(metric);

if (!invert) {
  if (count > parseInt(Min) && Min) {
    className = 'Class A';
  }

  if (count > parseInt(Max) && Max) {
    className = 'Class B';
  }
} else {
  if (count < parseInt(Min) && Min) {
    className = 'Class A';
  }

  if (count < parseInt(Max) && Max) {
    className = 'Class B';
  }
}

return className;
```

Is there a way to refactor this code further. I have tried adding the 'invert' condition check inside the if check itself. But still is there a better way than this ?

```
  if ((!invert && count > parseInt(Min)) || (invert && count < parseInt(Min)) && Min) {
    className = 'Class A';
  }


  if ((!invert && count > parseInt(Max)) || (invert && count < parseInt(Max)) && Max) {
    className = 'Class B';
  }
```

Comment: what are the possible values of `Min` and `Max`?

Comment: This looks more like a code review than an SO question.

Comment: A good approach in such cases is to write a *truth table*. Literally write a table on a sheet of paper, the values of each relevant variable in a row, and the result in the last column. Do that for all permutations. You'll find the pattern and can implement that in code…

Comment: Going by the 2nd approach.. set className to "Class A" by default and check only for 2nd condition and update className if that condition satisfies

Comment: @NinaScholz They are integers greater than zero

Comment: @KarthikGanesan there can even cases where i dont want either of them to apply

Comment: Why use parseInt if they are integers already?

Comment: @MinusFour apparently the values that are returned are sometimes converted into a string, so I am just checking for edge cases too

Comment: Is this for performance, for fun ? IMHO avoid doing this for professional code, write more 'simple' code instead if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You could omit `parseInt`, because you use either integers or greater or smaller check converts to number already.

```
let invert = moreIsBetter.includes(metric);

if (!invert && count > Min || invert && count < Min) {
    className = 'Class A';
}

if (!invert && count > Max || invert && count < Max) {
    className = 'Class B';
}
```

Comment: `className` cannot be both `Class A` and `Class B`, so using an `else` somewhere would be more readable I suppose

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy, it takes the last assignment. the question states no different behaviour.